# Trying to understand theorem 7.1.22 from the book the analysis of linear partial differential operators I, Hormander.

Tags: operator-theory

I am reviewing some concepts of differential operators from the book The analysis of linear partial differential operators, volume I by the author Hormander. I am stuck at a step in the proof of Theorem 7.1.22 in the image.

A differential operator with $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ coefficients of order $m$ in an open set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is of the form $P=P(x,D)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_{\alpha}(x)D^{\alpha}$.

**Definition.** The principal part $P_m$ is defined by $P_m(x,\xi)=\sum_{|\alpha|= m}a_{\alpha}(x)\xi^{\alpha}$

**Definition**. A homogeneous polynomial $P(\xi)$ in $n$ variables, with complex coefficients, is called elliptic if $p(\xi)\neq 0,\, 0\neq \xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$. An inhomogeneous polynomial is called elliptic if the homogeneous part of highest degree is elliptic.

[image]

In the theorem 7.1.22.

**Question 1**. Why $|P_m(\xi)|\geq c>0$ when $|\xi|=1$?

Comment: The function $P_m|$ is  continuous and does not  vanish on a compact set (unit sphere). Hence it is bounded below by its minimal value (which is positive).

Comment: I see. $c=\min_{|\xi|=1}|P_m(\xi)|>0$ thanks